# Is there a quick way to replace all of the content of h2 tags?

Tags: javascript

Can I quickly replace all the content of `<h2>` tags with javascript? My current code is this:

```
 var li = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
 console.log(li);
 for (var i = 0; i <= li.length; i++) {
   li[i].innerText = "something";
 }
```

What I thought this would do is create a list of all the `h2` tags and convert all of their content to `"something"`. Clearly this does not work, but is there and efficient way to do this?

Comment: In some browsers it's `.innerText`, in others `.textContent`.  But that's exactly how you'd do it. What makes you think it doesn't work? Do you get an error? If so, what exactly?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

Comment: How are you running that code in the page?  If you include the script too early in the page it may be running before any of those elements exist.

Comment: Your current loop does not apply to the last element. Use `<` instead of `<=`.

Answer (score 2):

Use innerHTML

```
 li[i].innerHTML="something";
```

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, it's .textContent which fixed it. The correct code is

```
 var li = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
 console.log(li);
 for (var i = 0; i <= li.length; i++) {
   li[i].textContent = "something";
 }
```

Credit to Pointy